# How to set primary key in SugarORM

Tags: android, primary-key, sugarorm

I'm using SugarORM for the first time and I have a quick question.
How can I set one entity as primary key ? For example, I need something like this:

```
public class Student{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String studentId;
    private String name;
}
```

Is it possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No way to specify primary key at the moment. But starting with sugar 1.4 there is an option to use @Unique attribute (https://github.com/satyan/sugar#sugarrecord):

```
public class Book extends SugarRecord {
    @Unique
    String isbn;
    String title;
    String edition;
    /*...*/
    public Book(String isbn, String title, String edition) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.title = title;
        this.edition = edition;
    }
}
```

It is not primary key but in many cases it does similar job (https://github.com/satyan/sugar#update-entity-based-on-unique-values):

```
Book book = new Book("isbn123", "Title here", "2nd edition")
book.save();

// Update book with isbn123
Book sameBook = new Book("isbn123", "New Title", "5th edition")
sameBook.update();

book.getId() == sameBook.getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't do this with Sugar ORM. The documentation on their website doesn't say anything about the primary key or even having such an annotation. You should consider switching to OrmLite which I personally recommend and is known to work good with Android.

http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

Answer (score 1):

I was trying too hard.

Finally, I got this answer code...

```
Book.deleteAll(Book.class);
book=new Book(user, pass);
book.setId(Long.valueOf(book.listAll(Book.class).size()));
book.save();
```

this code work like delete and recreating the table.and reset id.
important:in work sugar orm in android studio must disable instant run.
good luck

Comment: important :in work sugar orm in android studio must disable instant run

Answer (score 0):

Sugar has a primary auto increment key field added by default. It should be accessible via "[student_obj].id" As far as creating your own custom name primary key field, I don't think you can do that (yet).

All mine are typically name "id" anyway, so it makes no difference to me if they are auto-created or I add them myself.

Answer (score 0):

Sugar has an auto-increment by default, but still, we can modify it using the code below. For example, BOOK is the table name, book is a variable of object class, Id is the primary key.

```
book.executeQuery("DELETE FROM " + "BOOK" + " WHERE " +"ID" + " = " + 1 + ";");
book.executeQuery("UPDATE " + "BOOK" + " SET " + "ID" + " = " +"ID" + " -1 " + " WHERE " + "ID" + " > " + 1 + ";");
```

Note sugar will always calculate key based on the previous entry. For resetting the sqlitesequence, use:

```
book.executeQuery("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME ='BOOK'");
```

Hope this helps someone.